# How to attack an opponent's weapon with rusting grasp

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat, weapons, touch-attacks

The spell description says that you can make a melee touch attack against a weapon held by an enemy in order to affect it with the spell. However I can't find rules anywhere about making such an attack, only the sunder rules (using CMB), or rules for attacking unattended objects. Does anyone know?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answered question can help you ;) [What is the touch AC of an attended object?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60225)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Like @Landir mentions, this question is *almost* a duplicate of [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60225/8610), but this question's focus on a specific spell, I think, makes it different *enough*. Nonetheless, I recommend reading that question and its answers for more information about touching attended objects. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make a house rule

The rules don't cover this precisely. Actually *hitting* a weapon in an attempt to deal the weapon enough damage to *destroy* it is generally done using the combat maneuver [sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder), but this is different (needing only a touch) *and* the spell [*rusting grasp*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/rusting-grasp) adds its own specific rules, however incomplete. Making touch attacks against [creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Touch-Attacks) and [unattended objects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects) *is* precisely covered by the rules, but making a touch attack against an opponent's *weapon*—an attended object that the opponent's usually trying to shove into your face—*isn't*. Mechanically, all that's said about making such an attempt is that—according to the spell *rusting grasp*, anyway—the *rusting grasp*er provokes an attack of opportunity from the weapon's wielder.

I suggest the following.

> #### House Rule: Touching a Foe's Weapon
>
> To touch a weapon an opponent wields, the attacker makes a [touch attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Touch-Attacks) against the opponent *except* that doing so provokes an attack of opportunity from the opponent *and* that the size bonus or penalty to Armor Class is based on the size of the opponent's weapon instead of the size of the opponent.
>
> - A light weapon is 2 size categories littler than the wielder, a one-handed weapon 1 size categories, and a 2-handed weapon the same size category. (Search for `Light, One-Handed, and Two-Handed Melee Weapons` [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons).)
> - Also see [Size and AC of Objects chart for size modifiers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#table-size-and-ac-of-objects).

This is similar to—yet less complicated than—the house rules proposed by this broader [question's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60225/8610) [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/60241/8610) addressing the touch AC of attended objects.

Note that this topic in general is rarely discussed, although it pops up occasionally when some wacky dude tries to use a spell creatively, such as in this [2011 Paizo messageboard thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mlrs&page=1?Does-the-Wizard-get-hit-with-an-AoO) that begins with a discussion of using of the spell [*shrink item*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shrink-item) on a foe's weapon that ends up using *rusting grasp* as precedent.

### On the efficacy of *rusting grasp* generally

Keep in mind that the 4th-level druid spell [*rusting grasp*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/rusting-grasp) usually just isn't a very good combat spell, mainly because "[m]agic items made of metal are immune to this spell." Thus by the time a level 7 druid *can* cast *rusting grasp*, if facing a lone foe, that foe'll likely be armed with a magic weapon and wearing magic armor, and, if facing multiple foes, it's a needless expenditure of resources to use multiple 4th-level *rusting grasp*s to destroy their nonmagical armor and weapons when the same character *could* use, for example, the 4th-level spell [*flame strike*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flame-strike) and burninate *all* his foes or the special ability [wild shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) to assume the form of [tiger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/felines/cat-great/tiger) and claw the crap out of them.

[Niche uses notwithstanding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-iron), while *rusting grasp*'s effects *are* unique—it's ability to instantly destroy a nonmagical metal weapon with no saving throw and no SR *is* interesting—, most of the time in a combat situation a druid's better off with a good, old-fashioned *flame strike*.