# Can Good Domain clerics bestow negative levels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons, cleric, alignment

According to the [good domain in PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/good-domain/), an 8th level cleric can bestow a weapon with the special weapon quality, 'holy'

> Holy Lance (Su): At 8th level, you can give a weapon you touch the holy special weapon quality for a number of rounds equal to 1/2 your cleric level. You can use this ability once per day at 8th level, and an additional time per day for every four levels beyond 8th.

and according to [weapon quality Holy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy), a weapon can bestow a negative level to evil creatures

> It bestows one permanent negative level on any evil creature attempting to wield it. The negative level remains as long as the weapon is in hand and disappears when the weapon is no longer wielded. This negative level cannot be overcome in any way (including by restoration spells) while the weapon is wielded.

As the power does not specify a save for 'attended objects', but a 'touch' does a cleric get the ability to use a melee touch attack to make a weapon, or even an improvised weapon like a shield, 'holy' and either disarm or cause a negative level to the evil creature holding it?

Comment: I like the way you think with this question

Comment: Thanks lol, I don't want my cleric players to be handing out negative levels like ghasts but at the same time I wouldn't mind if it was RAW, I find it justifiable ingame anyway.

Comment: Honestly I feel there needs to be some sort of save, because otherwise they get a negative level or they drop their weapon, seems a bit too powerful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Making an evil foe's weapon gain the weapon special ability [*holy*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy) causes the foe to gain a [negative level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Energy-Drain-and-Negative-Levels) while the weapon's wielded

While the [Good domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/good-domain)'s supernatural ability holy lance's duration continues *and* the foe continues to wield the weapon, the foe will have that [negative level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Energy-Drain-and-Negative-Levels). *But* the GM must assess *how* the cleric touches a foe's weapon in combat, as the game instead expects an attacker to strike a foe's weapon to damage it using the combat maneuver [sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder). Fortunately, house rules for touching an foe's weapon in combat are present in answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60225/8610) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77266/8610).

A level 8 cleric that opts to use his 1/day ability to take a standard action to touch a foe's weapon so that his foe gains a negative level instead of opting to just clubstab that obviously evil foe with a now-[*holy*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/holy) morningstar is, however, likely in the minority of holy warriors.

Comment: Perhaps a reasonable comparison is with the 1st-level Clr spell [*burning disarm*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/burning-disarm), making this, effectively, a 4th-level version of that (as the supernatural ability holy lance become available when the cleric can cast 4th-level spells).