# Can you detect invisibility with arrows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, invisibility

If I shot an invisible creature with an arrow (perhaps by pinpointing it after it cast a spell) would the arrow disappear, or would it visibly stick to the creature and allow one to pinpoint it with greater ease?

For reference, I'm playing the Rise of the Runelords AP and we encountered a small demon in some catacombs who was invisible.  She cast a spell at us and my ally successfully pinpointed her and hit her with an arrow.  We're doing a play by post so that's where we've left off, but the GM is at a loss as to what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know it might not seem like it on the surface, but dig deeper and closely related is [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60094/8610).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [rules for invisible creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Invisibility) and the [*invisibility* spell itself](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility), objects the creature picks up while invisible would remain visible unless they were tucked into a pouch or pocket (where you wouldn't normally be able to see them even if the creature were visible), so the arrow should at least mark the creature's square for you (you'll still suffer the miss chance for attacking an invisible creature, but won't have to guess the square).

Many small demons and devils, including quasits, imps, and zebubs have *invisibility* as an at-will power - so the creature can spend a single standard action to become invisible again on its next turn, and then a move action to move to a new square so you'll have no clue where it is again.  Or, even more economically, he could pull the arrow out as a move action (unless it's one of the arrow types that embed in the target) and drop it as a free action...

Comment: The demon in question is actually a Quasit, who also have at-will invisibility. But even if it did not, it has hands, so can pull the arrow out and throw it away. This would be especially painless if the arrow is not made of cold iron.

Comment: I KNEW there was an imp-like demon, I just couldn't think of it!  Thanks.